# How to dynamically retrieve the type of data binding and fields?

Tags: android, data-binding

Say I have a `BaseActivity` that defines a skeleton for all of my activities:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();
    protected abstract void loadData();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, getLayoutResourceId());
        binding.refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        onRefresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        binding.refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        loadData();
        binding.refreshLayou.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

All of my activities will implement SwipeRefreshLayout so I don't want to define 
And I have a `MainActivity` that extends this class:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    protected void loadData() {
        // implement load data with API call here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // TODO: I need to somehow get ActivityMainBinding here and do other stuff unique to ActivityMainBinding here:
    }
}
```

Since I'm calling `setContentView` in `BaseActivity` dynamically, the type of binding is not known at compile time, so `ViewDataBinding` is used. For `MainActivity`, `ActivityMainBinding` extends `ViewDataBinding` and will be the binding created in the `onCreate` method. But how do I retrieve that binding as `ActivityMainBinding` instead of `ViewDataBinding` so I can access the views?

`BaseActivity` does not have a layout defined, yet it's defining that a `refreshLayout` exists for whatever binding that's created at runtime (yes all my `SwipeRefreshLayout`s will be named `refreshLayout`. So I only need to implement the `loadData` for each Activity. But refreshLayout does not exist when I compile there's error then.

Comment: Maybe make `BaseActivity` take a generic type? for example `BaseActivity<T extends ViewDataBinding>` and when you extend it, provide the bind type.

Comment: As already mentioned check https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm/ui/login/LoginActivity.java and this https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm/ui/base/BaseActivity.java